# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest returns (401) Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have a PowerShell script which runs in `ValidateService` of `CodeDeploy`. Below are few lines of code, where I get error:

```
$instancePrivateIp = Invoke-RestMethod http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4

# $instancePrivateIp --> 20.12.xx.yyy
# $instancePrivateIp.GetType() -->
# IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
# -------- -------- ----                                     --------
# True     True     String                                   System.Object

$uri = "http://{0}:8080/api/2.0/GetVersion" -f $instancePrivateIp
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri
$statusCode = $response | Select-Object -Expand StatusCode
...
...
```

When CodeDeploy executes this script I get (401) Unauthorized. Below is the complete message:

```
[stdout]Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
[stdout]At C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\7f9ade01-914b-44d7-9f7a-030e7aefe75e\d-T4EL
[stdout]8RNVB\deployment-archive\scripts\verify_deployment.ps1:12 char:25
[stdout]+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri
[stdout]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[stdout] + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
[stdout] pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
[stdout] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
[stdout] ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Whereas if I execute manually this script on same EC2 machine it gives me 200 response. I tried adding some sleep and hitting that API for 15 minutes but I get 401 all the times. Can someone please help me.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Can you show us the value of `$instancePrivateIp` and `$instancePrivateIp.GetType()`?

Comment: @Theo I have added it in the question now.

Comment: Thanks, looks fine to me.. Are you sure you want `http` and not `https`?

Comment: Yes, it's `http`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You are double hopping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=The%20%22second%20hop%20problem%22%20refers%20to%20a%20situation,access%20a%20resource%20on%20ServerC.%20More%20items...%20), which is likely not allowed in your organization by default. Double-hopping is connecting to a remote system and attempting to *implicitly* use the credential used to authenticate to the first system to authenticate to a second system. This is generally considered insecure to allow this behavior unchecked.

---

If `CodeDeploy` is running a command you crafted to connect to the instance and run your script, you can try using the `CredSSP` authentication mechanism, if your organization hasn't disabled it. Otherwise, you will need to have the service account delegated to be able to make the second hop (off topic for Stack Overflow), or you can explicitly pass the username and password from `CodeDeploy` as a script parameters (**DON'T** pass a built `PSCredential` as a parameter to a remote system, you won't be able to decrypt it unless you have the decryption key available there), and build the `PSCredential` object on the fly in your script.

> ***WARNING: While tempting because it's easy, don't hard-code your credentials***

Comment: Thanks, I am passing credentials and now I don't get 401 anymore.